# Where do I put ATL dlls so they will work

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, dll, plugins, atl

A colleague developed a IE Plugin which I require to run for a piece of work using ATL. I have all of the source code and the compiled dll as well as a regedit.

I have run the reg edit and moved the dll to the C:\Windows\System32 directory where I thought it was supposed to reside but that doesn't appear to have worked.

Where should I put the dll for it to run correctly?

Also is there a simple way to tell if the plugin has been installed correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about this IE plugin.

You should register your DLL using regsvr32.exe. This will register the COM classes (add some entries in windows registry). The path where DLL was stored when registering is the one considered when instantiating the COM class.

If the dll was previously registered in system32 and you want to move it, you should first unregister it (again, with regsvr32 /u), move the DLL and re-register it in the new location.

Comment: as a side question.

If I unregister the dll I am unable to delete the dll from its current location because it is in use. What do I have to do to be able to delete the dll once it is unregistered?

Comment: If you can't delete DLL, it seems it is already in use. First of all, try to close all the applications/processes that might use this DLL. This includes IE. If it doesn't work... restart Windows.